# How secure is sending a password to the server unencrypted in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

In a GWT application, I am building a login system.

I have implemented BCrypt, on the server side. My User class is only on the server side, as to protect the data. I have made the following assumptions, and cannot work out if they are correct:

- Since client side java is converted to javascript, I should not save the password's content in a client side variable, since it will be readable.
- For the same reason, I should send it over to the server already hashed.
- I should not put my User class in shared, because I do not want its properties readable/derivable from source code.

I have seen many examples, but none encrypt the password before sending it to the server. Is this safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to send the password unencrypted to the server as long as you are using a secure channel like HTTPS.

You can also keep the same user object (without storing the password) in memory for performance reasons, just make sure you always validate it on the server side. Never trust user information given to you by the client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! To your point of storing the User object in memory without the password I'd want to add that you'd also remove the salt from it, since you don't want it to be available in anyway either.

Any ideas in the case of not having a secure channel available, and still wanting to use salts for hashing?

Comment: Without a secure channel your only hope is security through obfuscation, and since the client literally has access to all your obfuscation code it's a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning (over two years later) that it's secure over HTTPS because HTTPS (by itself) is an ENCRYPTED channel.  So when the answer says "It's ok to send the password unencrypted" ... just be aware .. encryption is still happening (which is why it's safe) .. you just don't need to manually encrypt it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing the password before sending it to the server proves nothing.  (Other than perhaps protecting the user form being compromised on other systems where they used the same password.)

**If the attacker has whatever it is you send from client to server, whether it is clear text or hash or quantum brainwaves, they have what they need to access the system.**

The sensitive information needs to be sent over an encrypted socket, then it does not matter how you encode it yourself.

Comment: So you are saying that any authentication that goes over an unencrypted connection is basically unsafe?

Comment: Pretty much, yup.  If you don't trust the network, you'll need a system that utilizes random key generators, smart cards, or similar.